# Multidimensional xarray where dorps coordinates?

Tags: python, where-clause, python-xarray

I have a multidimensional variable which I would like to mask it using a multidimensional mask. However, using `xarray.where` drops the coordinates of the variable. Here is an example using very small files (link to download var file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cx6cMwSgshzrLKX2HfQFD1F8021AhDph/view?usp=sharing) and mask file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16d-2y-LEssub9hsCd9Fgt8Wtciagk1Rz/view?usp=sharing)):

```
import xarray as xr
mask = xr.open_dataarray("mask.nc")
var = xr.open_dataarray("var.nc")

masked_var = var.where(mask,drop=False)

>>> print(mask.shape)
(3, 3, 101, 101)
>>> print(var.shape)
(3, 3, 101, 101)
>>> print(masked_var.shape)
(1, 3, 101, 101)  # Note expected dimension is (3, 3, 101, 101)
```

As you can see `where` dropped coordinates.
My expected behavior is:

```
var.isel(lat=0,lon=0).where(mask.isel(lat=0,lon=0))
var.isel(lat=1,lon=1).where(mask.isel(lat=1,lon=1))
.
.
.
#for all lat and lon, resulting in masked_var with (3, 3, 101, 101) shape.
```

Comment: Can you reduce the example into something someone can copy paste?

Comment: I think we found the main issue. It has something to do with coordinates that are very close but not exactly the same.  https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/discussions/332